# Decrypting the payload in hyperledger

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I am currently using Developer Environment for Hyperledger Fabrics. I tried using GET to retrieve block info and it does give me a response. However, in the response, there's one component called payload, and it's in a unreadable format. Is there a way to make it readable/decrypt it? For instance, in bluemix, when you do init of party "a" and party "b", the payload shows inita100b100.

Firstly, I did this transaction/REST request

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "invoke",
  "params": {
      "type": 1,
      "chaincodeID":{
          "name":"mycc"
      },
      "ctorMsg": {
         "function":"invoke",
         "args":["a", "b", "100"]
      }
  },
  "id": 3
}
```

Then I did this query request

```
GET/localhost:5000/transactions/c6b0c82d-27f9-4c2c-8305-34b413d95057
```

and got back this as REST response

```
{
  "type": 2,
  "chaincodeID": "EgRteWNj",
  "payload": "Ch8IARIGEgRteWNjGhMKBmludm9rZRIBYRIBYhIDMTAw",
  "uuid": "c6b0c82d-27f9-4c2c-8305-34b413d95057",
  "timestamp": {
    "seconds": 1469643763,
    "nanos": 524731069
  }
}
```

So if there's anyway to decrypt/change `Ch8IARIGEgRteWNjGhMKBmludm9rZRIBYRIBYhIDMTAw` to showing `A transferred 100 to b` or something similar, at least being readable for less-technical users?

Comment: Please post the exact query that you sent, and exact response you got.

Comment: @DavisBroda Added.

Comment: Do you have privacy turned on?

Comment: @DavisBroda how do I check if my privacy is turned on or not?

Comment: It's a setting when you start the peers. So that means it's either supplied as a command line argument, or it's in one of the config files.

Comment: @DavisBroda I checked my privacy when I ran my peers. However, my payload is still in a very cryptic manner whenever I does a transaction. Do you have any idea..?

Comment: "I checked my privacy..." Was it on or off? You don't actually answer the question, you just say you checked it.

Comment: @DavisBroda Sorry for my bad answering. I checked my privacy, it was shown False. Security as well. So I do not know where the problem lies at.

Comment: try running the block-listener found at fabric/examples/events/block-listener. It should give you the raw block that was put on the chain, which contains your transaction. To filter out the junk, put `fmt.Printf("\nPayload: " + string(r.Payload))` inside the `for _, r := range b.Block.Transactions` loop, so that you don't have to go through the whole mess of looking through the block directly. This should tell you whether the block is encrypted on the chain, or just when sent to you. I suspect it is encrypted on the chain, but best to check.

Comment: Also, how are you enabling/disabling privacy? through a command line arg - what I use in my testing - or through the config file? If you're doing it through the file, try restarting everything with a command line arg to disable privacy, and submit a new transaction, and check. If that fixes it, then it's probably an issue of not reading the config file properly.

Answer (score 3):

The payload is just encoded, you can use [this](https://www.base64decode.org/) to decode it (the encoding is base64). There is also [this function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp) in javascript to decode it.

If you had security/privacy enabled, the payload would be encrypted too, so you would need the Certificate to decrypt the payload and then you could decode it.